# Changing picture caption with onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a thumbnail image that when you click it changes a larger image on the page.  So far I have the Javascript figured out for passing on the .src, .alt, and .title information that makes the picture and tool tip of the picture change.

The large picture has a caption underneath.  I was wondering how to also have the caption change when the thumbnail is clicked.  I'm assuming I can change it into some sort of Javascript variable but this is my first time using JS so I am still very green.

Comment: pls post some code. what does your caption property(?) looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have the caption in a container with an ID, and overwrite the innerHTML of that container.  i.e.

```
<div id="myCaption">People of Walmart</div>

<script type=text/javascript>
document.getElementById('myCaption').innerHTML = 'Whoa!';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your caption has an ID you can select that caption and add the text through JS:

```
document.getElementById('id_of_the_caption').innerHTML = "Text to display";
```

Use that JS code in your function that changes the image.